# Is there any number which is a perfect square of some number as well as factorial of some number.

Tags: number-theory, factorial

Is there any number which is a perfect square of some number as well as factorial of some number?

That is, let x be such a number, then x can be expressed as

```
             x = k^2 (for some k)
```

and,         x = n! (for some n)

The very trivial answer is 1. But is there any number other than 1?

Comment: If this is true, there is no prime that is larger than $\frac{p}{2}$ and less than or equal to $p$, where $p$ is some solution.

Comment: $$7!=71^2.  {}{}{}{}{}{} $$